# Primary Key & checking Uniqueness in insertion in a table in a DB

Tags: database, rdbms

In a database (eg: MySQL) how does the database internally check for unique key when insertion is happening. For example if we insert a row into a table with a value(primary key) already exists how does the DB check where that value exists. Is it comparing it with all keys in the table. Wouldnt that make it slow?

Comment: What's "slow"? What's "not slow"?

Answer (score 0):

Primary Key is always indexed. Searching an indexed field is faster than searching a field sequentially. More on MySQL indexes is given in below:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

More on Indexes ( types, cases ) can be found below:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-indexes.htm